# Phaser 3, loader plugin not load assets in pack.json file

Tags: phaser-framework

I have a json file for load assets generated with phaser editor.
i have a file boot.js for load a image for make load bar, and preloasder.js for load other assets file.
in the browser console does not appears some kind of error, but the image isn't load.

boot.js

```
 runner.Boot.prototype = {
           preload: function() {
               this.load.pack('boot', 'assets/pack.json'); //this not work
               //this.load.image('logo','assets/img/logo.png');//this work
               resize();
           },
[...]
update: function(){
      this.scene.start('Preloader');
  }
```

in file preloader.js

```
this.preloadLogo = this.add.sprite(0, 0, 'logo');
```

but the key 'logo' is not load.
the file content in pack.json has not been loaded.

[image]

the content of pack.json

```
    {
  "boot": [{
    "type": "image",
    "key": "logo",
    "url": "assets/img/logo.png",
    "overwrite": false
  }],
  "preloader": [
    {
      "type": "spritesheet",
      "key": "coin",
      "url": "assets/img/coin.png",
      "frameWidth": 20,
      "frameHeight": 20,
      "frameMax": -1,
      "margin": 0,
      "spacing": 0
    },
    {
      "type": "spritesheet",
      "key": "fire",
      "url": "assets/img/fire.png",
      "frameWidth": 40,
      "frameHeight": 70,
      "frameMax": -1,
      "margin": 0,
      "spacing": 0
    },
    {
      "type": "spritesheet",
      "key": "gattoboy",
      "url": "assets/img/gattoboy.png",
      "frameWidth": 64,
      "frameHeight": 128,
      "frameMax": -1,
      "margin": 0,
      "spacing": 0
    },
    {
      "type": "spritesheet",
      "key": "mountain",
      "url": "assets/img/mountain.png",
      "frameWidth": 512,
      "frameHeight": 512,
      "frameMax": -1,
      "margin": 0,
      "spacing": 0
    },
    {
      "type": "image",
      "key": "platform",
      "url": "assets/img/platform.png",
      "overwrite": false
    },
    {
      "type": "image",
      "key": "loader",
      "url": "assets/img/loader.png",
      "overwrite": false
    },
    {
      "type": "image",
      "key": "five",
      "url": "assets/img/five.png",
      "overwrite": false
    },
    {
      "type": "image",
      "key": "loader-frame",
      "url": "assets/img/loader-frame.png",
      "overwrite": false
    },
    {
      "type": "image",
      "key": "phaser",
      "url": "assets/img/phaser.png",
      "overwrite": false
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "generated": "1576167834682",
    "app": "Phaser Editor",
    "url": "http://phasereditor.boniatillo.com",
    "version": "1.0",
    "copyright": "Arian Fornaris (c) 2015,2016"
  }
}
```